# Virtual size and physical size

Tags: portable-executable

Im analysing a PE exectuable, i want to know why the physical size is less than the virtual size for the second section?

00000FEC and 00000E00

Exactly what is the Physical size and how is it calculated? Sometimes its more than the virtual size, sometimes its less than the virtual size

```
#  Name   VirtSize RVA      PhysSize Offset
1 .text   000C44C1 00001000 000C4600 00000800
2 .data   00000FEC 000C6000 00000E00 000C4E00
3 .rsrc   00000520 000C7000 00000600 000C5C00
4 .reloc  0000B098 000C8000 0000B200 000C6200
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "VirtSize" is what ELF calls "memsz" and "PhysSize" is what ELF calls "filesz" (ELF has much better names). Note that "virtual memory" in the sense of an MMU is generally unrelated. I do know that (on ELF) `memsz` is smaller because it doesn't include BSS (which is initialized to 0). I speculate that file size might be rounded up?

Comment: It might be the alignment possibly

Answer (score 1):

The virtual size represents the "actual" size of the section, once it has been mapped to memory, whereas the physical size is the number of bytes allocated in the PE file for the section data. Note that the physical size is always a multiple of the file block size (512 bytes), so it might contain some padding bytes after the bytes that correspond to actual section data.

If the physical size is larger than the virtual size, it is precisely because the section data is padded out to a multiple of the file block size (you can see that the difference in size will be less than 512 bytes).

If the virtual size is larger than the physical size, it is because the section ends with zero/null-bytes, and the zeros are not represented explicitly in the PE file to save space.